# Recursively fill an ArrayList with all possible Boolean values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, permutation

I am trying to fill an array with boolean values such that I return a different array each time, eventually having returned all possible arrays.

Example output for array size 5: [True, True, True, True, True]
                           Then: [True, True, True, True, False]
And so on and so forth...

I am aware of code that would fill a smaller array with all combinations from a bigger array but i can not do it the other way around

Answer (score 1):

binary representation from 0 to 2^n.

00000
00001
00010
00011
...

11111